# Can’t run SKAction.runBlock in a Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am new to Swift but I am having trouble with classes and inheritance. I have a class called Bunny which holds some code including an SKAction. When I place the code found in Bunny into my GameScene class, it works fine, however, when I try running it, while it is in the Bunny class, from my GameScene class it does not work.

Here is the Bunny class:

```
import SpriteKit

class Bunny : SKSpriteNode {
    var bunny = SKSpriteNode()
    var moveAndRemove = SKAction()
    var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

    func spawnBunnies() {
        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({
            () in
                self.spawnBunny()
                print("CALLEDBunniesSpawned") // THIS PART IS NOT GETTING CALLED
            })
        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)
        let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
        let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnDelay)
        self.runAction(spawnDelayForever)
        let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + bunny.frame.width)
        let movePipes = SKAction.moveByX(-distance - 200, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.009 * distance)) // Speed up pipes
        let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes, removePipes])
        print("BunniesSpawned") // THIS PART HERE RUNS
    }

    func spawnBunny() { // I NEED TO TRIGGER THIS PART VIA THE SPAWN = SKAction.runBlock
        print("BunniesSpawned2")
        let randomYGen = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height - 80)))
        textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Bunnies")
        for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {
            var name = "Bunny\(i).png"
            textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
        }
        bunny = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: textureAtlas.textureNames[5] as! String)
        bunny.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + bunny.frame.width / 2, y: randomYGen)
        bunny.setScale(0.5)
        bunny.runAction(moveAndRemove)
        self.addChild(bunny)
        bunny.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)))
    }
}
```

Here is my GameScene class where I am trying to call the function from Bunny:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    if gameStarted == false {
        gameStarted = true

        var bun = Bunny()
        bun.spawnBunnies()

    } else {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something you are not adding the Bunny subclass to the scene.

Try this

```
 var bun = Bunny()
 addChild(bun)
 bun.spawnBunnies()
```

Answer (score 2):

As crashoverride777 said, the original `Bunny` you created in your `touchesBegan` is never added to the scene. If it is not part of a scene, it will never run any of the actions you are setting up.

```
var bun = Bunny()
self.addChild(bun)
bun.spawnBunnies()
```

Additionally, in `spawnBunnies` you are adding the newly spawned `Bunny` as a child of the `Bunny` that is spawning it. This bunny gets removed from the scene so the newly spawned bunny (which is it's child) also get's removed.

`self.addChild(bunny)` should be `parent?.addChild(bunny)`. It might also need to be moved above the line `bunny.runAction(moveAndRemove)`.